# Lambda function in python for changing the file's updated date in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an XML file in S3 which does not require any changes as such, but the last updated date for it should be the most recent date.

I was wondering to use a Lambda function to create this process.

Can you suggest python code for Lambda or any other process to change the updated date of a file?

Comment: you could perform the copyObejct operation with CopySource and Key the same URI string value.

Comment: You might also need to change something about the object (eg Metadata), otherwise it won't let you copy an object on top of itself. Or, it might be easier to simply upload the file again.

Comment: What language? This question is missing details - to change updated data based on a schedule? Manually? In Python? JavaScript? .NET?

Answer (score 0):

I am renaming the xml file twice (once from test.xml to test1.xml and then back from test1.xml to test.xml) to changed the last update date of the file to most recent date.

```
copy_source = {'Bucket': 'bucket', 'Key': 'folder/test.xml'}
s3.copy_object(CopySource = copy_source, Bucket = 'bucket', Key = 'folder/test1.xml')
s3.delete_object(Bucket = 'bucket', Key = 'folder/test.xml')

copy_source = {'Bucket': 'bucket', 'Key': 'folder/test1.xml'}
s3.copy_object(CopySource = copy_source, Bucket = 'bucket', Key = 'folder/test.xml')
s3.delete_object(Bucket = 'bucket', Key = 'folder/test1.xml')
```